# How to create a custom button to video play

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create a custom button to play the videos on my web page, the videos are from MySQL database, I am finding it difficult to pass the row id from MySQL database to my JavaScript function so that each of the video can play when the button is clicked. Here are my code

```
$q2="SELECT * FROM `video` "  ;
   $r2= mysqli_query($con, $q2) ; 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r2)){
       $img = $row['vid'];

?>
<button onclick="play()">play</button>
 <video id="myvideo" data-id="<?php echo $id ?>"  style="width:100%; height:400px;"  controls   />
 <source  style="width:100%; height:400px;" src="video/<?php echo $vid ; ?>"  />
 </video>
<?php } ?>
```

And here is the jQuery function

```
<script>
function play(){
    var vid = $('#myvideo').data('id');
    vidd.get(0).play();
}


    </script>
```

Comment: you are using wrong variable `vidd` it is `vid`

Answer (score 0):

In general, just sending the bytes doesn't work because the browser doesn't know what the file type is or how to interpret them.

I have recently started embedding Base64 images and MP3s in the src attribute in IMG and AUDIO tags. Aside from content size, I see no reason this wouldn't work for MP4 and VIDEO. But in the Base64 solution, it states "Base64-encoded image/png" or "Base64-encoded image/jpeg" right at the start.

If you are already aware of this and/or this is not a solution you want to consider, please tell me (or downclick) and I'll delete